# How to initialize new DOM contents using JavaScript and keep previous DOM somewhere else?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have two pages:

1. page1.html
2. page2.html

page1.html is :

```
<html>
<head>Some CSS and JS goes here</head>
<body><a href="page2.html"></a></body>
</html>
```

page2.html is :

```
<html>
<head> few more CSS and JS goes here</head>
<body><a href="page3.html"></a></body>
</html>
```

My plan is:
When user clicks on

```
<a href="page2.html"></a>
```

I grab content of page2.html via Ajax and store contents of page1.html in a JavaScript variable

Now how can I insert content of page2.html in DOM and initialize it so that all the `$(document).ready` events in JavaScript of page2.html must be triggered.

Comment: What you want to do is really not the way things work.

Comment: Document ready is only going to fire on an initial page load. Once the document is ready the first time, it is always ready after that. You're trying to do a full page replacement using Ajax, which kind of defeats the purpose of using it in the first place.

Comment: @Pointy I am trying to make something like jQueryMobile framework. I am not sure how it works internally but essentially it does the same. Makes div and show and hide them..

Comment: @zclark No, I will save contents of page1.html in a javascript varible (kind of catch) and show it when user reverts to page1 from any other page from site.